# DatePicker format date as system locale

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to format a `Date` according to the system locale. I know I can use `DateFormat`, but I just can't seem to get it right! I also tried `SimpleDateFormat` but it doesn't respect locale and most of all it is deprecated!

Below is my current code, the `DatePickerDialog` is shown when an `EditText` gets focus. The problem is a `NullPointerException` that occurs because the `DateFormat` returns null!

What am I doing wrong? Can anybody please help me?

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if (v == txtDate) {
        if (hasFocus == true) {

            // Process to get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Launch Date Picker Dialog
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    // Display Selected date in edit text
                    String selectedDate = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    Date date = null;
                    try {
                        date = sdf.parse(selectedDate);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // handle exception here !
                    }

                    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(activityname.this);
                    String s = dateFormat.format(date);
                    txtDate.setText(s);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `DateFormat` to format a `Date` according to the current locale:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat format =  DateFormat.getDateInstance();
String formatted = format.format(date);
```

Depending on which instance of `DateFormat` you use the `Date` is formatted in different ways:

1. `DateFormat.getDateInstance()`: Outputs the date only
2. `DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()`: Outputs date and time
3. `DateFormat.getTimeInstance()`: Outputs the time only

But aside from that you don't need to do anything. `DateFormat` takes care of everything and correctly formats the `Date`.

You can find more information about `DateFormat` [**in the documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html).

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Sounds simple but I still struggle. I have it like this now  `Date date = new Date();  DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance();  String formatted = format.format(date);  txtDate.setText(formatted);`  but `getDateInstance()`is undefined for the type DateFormat and `format`  in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Date)

Comment: That's because you are using the wrong `DateFormat`. There are multiple classes which are called `DateFormat`. Check your imports at the top of the file. What you need is `import java.text.DateFormat;`.

Comment: That did the trick! I had `import android.text.format.DateFormat;` which I'm using forthe TimePicker `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)`which is now not working anymore because of the same issue as I had to remove the non-java DateFormat import. Can't have both, right?  If you don't mind, do you have also a suggestion for `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this)`?

Comment: No you can have both, but you can only have one import for `DateFormat`. If you import `java.text.DateFormat` then you can access the other `DateFormat` by using the fully qualified package name, in your case try this: `android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this);`.

Comment: Aha, now I've learned again a lot :-) Thanks a lot, issue solved!